# How can I change life on a planet and the presence of Nitrogen in the nitrogen cycle and what effects are there

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, xenobiology, earth-like

Nitrogen makes up most of our atmosphere, it gets fixed by bacteria, legumes, etc., and enters the soil in a different form to be used by plant life. The nitrogen gets buried in sedimentary rock over time until it is released into the atmosphere by tectonic activity. Nitrogen in the soil is a limiter, in most places there's more growth and plant activity than there is in the soil. Increasing the supply in the soil could change soil composition in a good way or eventually at a high enough rate I am sure in a bad way. On earth nitrogen can negatively effect certain ecosystems so I would expect plant life on a world to evolve differently. I also know that nitrogen narcosis puts the limit on pressure at 2-4 Atmospheres for humans. So I ask how much more nitrogen in an atmosphere and soil could an alien world have, and what kind of changes to plant life or the  equivalent would people see. I don't think I want more than 2 bar or atm.

Edit: logging in through gmail is a hassle, anyways, the Question is somewhat correct, and somewhat wrong. There is a large amount of activity within the nitrogen cycle, but after looking at the surface has to offer, it appears that we should focus first on nitrates and nitrites in the soil. These have limits for plant life, eventually too much in the soil will prevent plants from finding anything else it needs, and it can lead to "root burn" or damage to it's leaves. There is also the question of storage and how much can the soil store before runoff becomes an issue. The answer and another place to store the nitrogen is within the plants themselves, it is possible as mentioned by myself that instead of increasing atmospheric nitrogen it could be drained for resources. ***So a better two questions would be in what ways can Plant or Fungal life use more nitrogen and how can we change nitrification or denitrification in a system***
Some answers would be to change photosynthesis and the use of sugars, cellulose, or really anything that a plant uses Carbon for.

So some possibilities would be in replacement of glucose with something that uses more nitrogen as energy storage seems to be a significant source of a demand for carbon in a plant, this is a good place as leaves use CO2, and the source of demand will be where it could take in N2.

Comment: So I know one other possibility is to actually have a change in nitrogen fixing life on the planet and have more of it in the soil through more efficient nitrogen fixing organisms. The problem would be figuring out the reason it would be any more efficient that it would change the amount in the atmosphere significantly without scrubbing the air so clean life couldn't handle the low pressure.

Comment: The word "in" has two very different meanings in the phrases "nitrogen in the air" and "nitrogen in the soil". The air actually contains nitrogen,; this is a mostly chemically inert gas, of which the main function is to serve as a buffer moderating the reactivity of oxygen; plants cannot use it. The soil contains ammonia and/or nitrates, nitrogen compounds which can actually be used by plants. Nitrogen from the air is converted to ammonia and/or nitrates by certain bacteria, and, most importantly, by large factories using the [Haber process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process).

Comment: Yes, I know that is why I made a difference between within the air and within the soil. Nitrogen in the air is fixed by one organism, it enters the soil and is used by the plants. Putting more in the air will lead to more in the soil, the proportion of nitrogen in the air goes up, the proportion in the soil due to the nitrogen cycle should go up as well.

Comment: Um I'm not seeing an actual question in the question here, what information are you after exactly?

Comment: Related: [Can plants thrive without atmospheric nitrogen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20153/22029)

Comment: @BlindingLight "Putting more in the air will lead to more in the soil" - not necessarily. It's not like the amount of atmospheric nitrogen is the limiting factor for nitrogen compounds production in the soil.

Comment: Ash and Alexander sorry about my wording it may be not be the best. I know the nitrogen is in the soil for the plants, I think the nitrogen fixing organism will take from the atmosphere and put it in the soil. I am under the impression more atmospheric nitrogen will lead to more in the soil, although Alexander seems to disagree. Thank you for solving half. I am trying to figure out how much more nitrogen can be put into the system and what effects putting more in it will have. Specifically for me I have a limit of the atmosphere not being any more than twice as big as our own.

Comment: @BlindingLight Raw nitrogen is basically saturated; it's not the limiting factor in the nitrogen cycle. The limiting factor is that a) living things have to spend energy to fix nitrogen, and they're not at all keen to waste it making more than they need, and b) excess oxygen is bad for the fixation process, so these organisms tend to be a little complex. The more "fixed" (usable) nitrogen there is, the worse they perform next to non-nitrogen-fixing organisms, so the cycle is self-limiting.

Comment: The Plants would still be able to use more of the nitrates and ammonia for themselves and there still be more nitrogen. Is the Nitrogen cycle unchangeable or does it change with the adaptation of organisms within it? I am familiar with plant life and animal life effecting the amount of oxygen in the atmosphere and changing based on changes to that quantity. Would organisms that fix nitrogen not change? Thank you for your input Cadence all of you are a help.

Comment: More nitrogen compounds in the soil will indeed lead to increased growth for nitrogen-neutral and denitrifying organisms, while encouraging nitrogen-fixing organisms to forgo fixation. However, unless some outside process is resupplying the nitrogen compounds, they'll eventually be used up, which will in turn encourage nitrogen fixation once more. The net result is that you tend to return to where you started.

Comment: So in conclusion there's a better way of adding nitrogen to the soil, and that might lead to more in the atmosphere so I was looking at this wrong, and the answer is essentially a different phrasing, at least to my ears. Or maybe my visualization fo the situation is just backwards. More nitrogen compounds in the soil is going to lead to more in the atmosphere and I should be looking at soil's proportion first, not the atmosphere's proportion. So there ends up being a precluding question to figure this out that I am unaware of that is how much nitrogen is in the soil in proportion to the air.

Comment: So with that precluding question, how much nitrogen is in our soil, how much more can plant life handle, or feasibly evolved to handle, and because of this increase, how will that effect nitrogen in the atmosphere? And if this increases the amount within the atmosphere how much would it be until we get to double the size in our atmosphere. Which seems at least to some extent researchable by me, and so which I will do.

Comment: *The system truly having no limits, and instead the limits being the plants. How much nitrogen compound can I put in before I get double the atmospheric pressure and how would that effect evolution of plant life.

Comment: So I did a bit more digging, one fun thing I noticed is Nitrate poisoning, if the plant life doesn't change enough to soak up that nitrogen and there's more in the soil, than eventually there will be enough that it could become toxic or at least in some way effect the blood of Earth animals including any human colonists.